# Como puedo hacer que me mande a un activity de acuerdo a la opcion de mi menu drawer layout?

Tags: android-drawerlayout

Ya tengo elaborado mi menú lateral, pero ahora necesito que al seleccionar alguna opción me mande al activity correspondiente. En seguida les dejo mi código:

```
public class cliente_inicio extends AppCompatActivity {


    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private ListView menuLateral;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cliente_inicio);

        ActionBar aBar = getSupportActionBar();
        aBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        aBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout= (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayaout);
        mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        menuLateral=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.menuLateral);

        String[] opciones={"Catalogo","Paquetes","Galeria","Contacto","Iniciar Sesion"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(cliente_inicio.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,opciones);
        menuLateral.setAdapter(adp);

        menuLateral.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String opcSeleccionado=(String) menuLateral.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(cliente_inicio.this, opcSeleccionado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cliente_inicio,menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id==android.R.id.home){
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(menuLateral)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuLateral);
            }else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(menuLateral);
            }
        }
        if (id==R.id.action_settings){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo suelo hacerlo a través de `Intent`, en el método `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Por ejemplo:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityQueSeLLamara.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_otra) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityOtra.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Aquí,

- En el `if` tienes que preguntar por el `id` de la opción que se ha seleccionado. En el ejemplo he usado `action_settings` y otro id hipotético `nav_otra` el cual tendrás que cambiar por alguna opción válida de tu menú.
- En el `Intent` el valor `this` representará la activity actual. También puedes ponerlo así `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityOtra.class);`, suponiendo que la activity en la cual tienes el drawer es `MainActivity`.
- `ActivityOtra.class` y `ActivityQueSeLLamara.class` son nombres ficticios que deberás cambiar por las activitys reales que quieras llamar en cada opción del menú que pulses.
- No he puesto este `if` en mi respuesta: `if (id==android.R.id.home){...` porque no atañe a la solución del problema. Lo digo porque no significa que debas borrar esa parte en tu método por el hecho de yo no la haya puesto en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias has resolvido mi duda

Comment: @Jessica me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.